# Integral of Bessel functions product times Gaussian

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, gaussian-integral

I have the following integral, which I dont know how to deal with:

$\int_0^\infty J_0(ax)J_0(bx)e^{-x^2}xdx.$

Integration by parts doesnt help.

I'm sure that integral must result in something like

$2\pi I_0(2ab)e^{-(a^2+b^2)},$

but I dont know how to prove it.

Comment: The expression you're looking for is $~\dfrac12\cdot{I_0\bigg(\dfrac{ab}2\bigg)}\cdot \exp\bigg(-\dfrac{a^2+b^2}4\bigg)$

Comment: Yes, thank you for clarification. Do you know a way to prove it ? Or could you please provide any reference ?

Comment: Maybe [this book](https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnTheTheoryOfBesselFunctions) might help.

Comment: Yes, it is there ! Thank you so much.