# Integral of product of zeroth-order bessel functions times cosine $\int J_{0}\left(\alpha x\right)J_{0}\left(\beta x\right)\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am new to Bessel functions and need to solve the following integral

\begin{equation}
\int J_{0}\left(\alpha x\right)J_{0}\left(\beta x\right)\cos(kx)\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}

with $J_{0}$ denothing the zeroth-order Bessel functions of the first kind, and real-valued parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $k$. I already checked Wolframalpha, Gradshteyn's book on integrals, and looked on the stackexchange forum, however without success. However, I found on [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+besselj%280%2Ck*x%29%5E%282%29+dx) and some similar related integrals in [Integral of squared absolute of Bessel function of first kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372947/integral-of-squared-absolute-of-bessel-function-of-first-kind), [Integral of squared Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244135/integral-of-squared-bessel-function/4244360#4244360), [How to derive a Hypergeometric function from the integration of the square of Bessel function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933710/how-to-derive-a-hypergeometric-function-from-the-integration-of-the-square-of-be). During my search I also came across the orthogonality property of Bessel functions as well as to a [product of Bessel functions with a Gaussian kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1476070/integral-of-bessel-functions-product-times-gaussian). However, it seems to me that my integrals of interest cannot be related to these approaches.

Do you know some strategy how to obtain a solution? Your help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: Partial help:  $\int B_0(x) B_0(x)\ dx = x \, _2F_3\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1,\frac{3}{2};-x^2\right)$